# Python-How to read a text file and convert to text file in list form

Tags: python

I am trying to get my Raspberry Pi to read a text file, then convert it to a list, as the title suggests. The text file is something like

```
0 122 122 0 124 0 0 0 0 0 0 155
```

Etc...
Anyway, I want it to convert the output text file as:

```
0
122
122
0
124
0 
0
0
0
0
0
155
```

can you help?

Comment: Can you post your efforts SO is not a code writing service

Comment: Read in all lines, use string.split(' ') to split with space, then loop over the result and print or write to file with the '\n' added at the end, which is the new line character. But as EdChum said, you should show the effort while posting on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should work for you:

```
with open('input.txt') as f_input, open('output.txt', 'w') as f_output:
    for line in f_input:
        f_output.write('\n'.join(line.strip().split()))
```

This will read lines from the file `input.txt`. For each line `strip` removes the newline at the end, and then `split` is used to create a list of numbers by splitting it up where the space characters are. Finally the `join` command combines the list of numbers back into a single string, with each number having a newline added. The write command then writes this string to the output file.

Also by using the `with` command, the two files are automatically closed afterwards.

Comment: So, Python opens the input text file. And creates a new output text file, then, for every line in the input file, it creates anew line in the output file, right? Then how does it know if the digits aretriple or single?

Comment: The `split` command creates a list of numbers. By default it splits on the spaces in the string.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
handle = open("num.txt",'r')
numbers = handle.read()
mylist = numbers.split()
print '\n'.join(mylist)
```